# Is it possible to prevent VISUAL STUDIO from automatically adding new line in DEBUG CONSOLE?

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

When I run this code on VSC:

```
numbers = [8, 18, 2, 4]
maxlen=len(numbers)
i=0
while i<maxlen:
    print (i, numbers[i])
    i=i+1
```

I get each output from **PRINT** function in separate row. I have tried using **'end'** parameter like that:

```
print(i, numbers[i], end=' ')
```

but with no success.

The same code executed on **Jupyter** looks fine.

Here you can find screens from both editors:

[Jupyter output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LROMx.png)

[Visual Studio Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcQRs.png)

Any tips greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try format(). 
It will create a string for each line. 
print('{0} {1}'.format(i, numbers[i]))

Comment: Very nice solution to a very weird problem. After using format() I was able to align the output in two rows, looking much better. So I added end = '  ' parameter and it worked perfectly. No extra empty lines between rows.